# UILabel in function in separate swift file

Tags: swift, iboutlet

I was wondering how to use a `UILabel`

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyLabel : UILabel!
```

in a function, in another swift file.

```
"SecondSwift file"

func MyFunc {
print(MyLabel.text = "")
}
```

Now I've got the problem that i can't use my `UILabel` in a separate swift file

I've got a lot of functions and my `MainViewController` gets chaotic if i need to make all my functions there.

So i was wondering if its possible to use a `UILabel` in a function in another swift file so i can use it later on

Comment: So you want to access `MyLabel` text in another swift file?

Comment: yes, i got MyLabel in my MainView,
and i want to create a swift file Example "MainFunc.swift"
and use MyLabel in that swift file :)

Comment: Since all my Functons change or print a UILabel or a UIButton, and al that code is kinda messy in 1 file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the purpose is to simply split up the source code related to `MainViewController` to more than one source file, you can create an extension to your class `MainViewController` in a separate `.swift` source file.

Consider the following simple example, consisting of two source files, `MainViewController.swift` and `MainViewControllerExtensions.swift`:

```
/* Source file: MainViewController.swift */
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    private var myPrivateInt = 1

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myLabel.text = "foo"

        /* member methods defined in separate source file      */
        foo()               /* set 'myLabel' text to "foobar"  */
        printLabel(myLabel) /* print text of UILabel argument; 
                               here, prints "foobar"           */
    }
}

/* Source file: MainViewControllerExtensions.swift */
extension MainViewController {

    func foo() {
        myLabel.text = "foobar"
        // myPrivateInt <-- not accessible in this scope
    }

    func printLabel(label: UILabel) {
        print(label.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

After the view has been loaded in the simple example above, your label will have text `"foobar"`.

Note however that extensions in separate source files cannot access *private* properties and methods from the main file. Most entities in swift, have, however, a default access level of *internal*; you can access internal properties and methods from a separate source file, as shown in the example above. So unless you explicitly define private access level for properties/methods, you will be able to access them in the separate-source-file extension.

For more information regarding access levels in Swift, please refer to the [Language Guide - Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Answer (score 0):

your UILabel property belongs to an instance of some class, so in order to access the label, you need to call a method on that class, or pass the instance of that class to your func.

`func myFunc(mainVC: MainViewController) {
    print(mainVC.MyLabel.text)
}`

Comment: If you call the MainView in your function do you still need to call it in 
print?
(Sorry i'm at work atm so can't test it yet) :D

Comment: if myLabel is a var inside mainVC then that's the only way to access it